# Error while trying to call detectintent api in nodejs-Dialogflow CX

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-cx

I am trying to send a request to  DetectIntent API from webhook - Dialog Flow CX . I downloaded service-key in GCP and stored in serviceaccount.json file .I created .env file and stored all the values from serviceaccount file to .env file.I get error when I run "node index.js"

```
Error:"IAM permission 'dialogflow.sessions.detectIntent' on 'projects/dialogflowcx-340818,/agent' denied.",
```

I went through related stackoverflow posts where they suggested to set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS .I tried that as well.Still I get the same error.

I tried :

```
process.env.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/Users/suchitranagarajan/Desktop/nodeproject/detectintent/service-account.json"
```

Also,I tried to set

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/Users/suchitranagarajan/Desktop/nodeproject/detectintent/service-account.json"
```

Please find the code below:

```
const dialogflow = require('@google-cloud/dialogflow');
test=require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const path = require("path");


process.env.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/Users/suchitranagarajan/Desktop/nodeproject/detectintent/service-account.json"

const PROJECTID = process.env.project_id;
const location=process.env.location
const agentid=process.env.agentid


const CONFIGURATION = {
    credentials: {
        private_key: process.env.private_key,
        client_email: process.env.client_email
    }
}

const sessionClient = new dialogflow.SessionsClient();

const detectIntent = async (languageCode, queryText, sessionId) => {

    let sessionPath = sessionClient.projectLocationAgentSessionPath(PROJECTID,location,agentid,sessionId);
    
    // The text query request.
    let request = {
        session: sessionPath,
        queryInput: {
            text: {
                // The query to send to the dialogflow agent
                text: queryText,
                // The language used by the client (en-US)
                languageCode: languageCode,
            },
        },
    };

    // Send request and log result
    const responses = await sessionClient.detectIntent(request);
    console.log(responses);
    const result = responses[0].queryResult;
    console.log(result);

    return {
        response: result.fulfillmentText
    };
}

detectIntent("en", "hello", "abcd1234");

// Start the webapp
const webApp = express();

// Webapp settings
webApp.use(express.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
webApp.use(express.json());

// Server Port
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

// Home route
webApp.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send(`Hello World.!`);
});

// Dialogflow route
webApp.post('/dialogflow', async (req, res) => {

    let languageCode = req.body.languageCode;
    let queryText = req.body.queryText;
    let sessionId = req.body.sessionId;

    let responseData = await detectIntent(languageCode, queryText, sessionId);

    res.send(responseData.response);
});

// Start the server
webApp.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is up and running at ${PORT}`);
});
```

Please find .env file below:

```
type= service_account,
project_id=xxx,
private_key_id=xxx,
private_key=xxx","client_email": "xxx","client_id": "xxx","auth_uri": "xxx,
token_uri=xxx,
auth_provider_x509_cert_url= xxx,
client_x509_cert_url=xxx
location=xxx
agentid=xxx
```

Comment: I am assuming you created a service account and you have downloaded the key JSON file for that service account.  That should mean that when your app runs, it runs as that service account.  However, the error message seems to imply that the service account hasn't been granted enough permissions.  Separate the notion of your app running "with" an identity from the notion of "what permissions" that identity posesses.  You may want to post back what permissions (GCP roles) you have granted the account.

Comment: Can you check the permissions of your service account and if your key/s is/are still active?

Comment: I am the owner of the service account(Role:Owner) and its still active.  @Kolban

Comment: @user10019895 Instead of using the Owner role, try using the Dialogflow API Admin permission so you can have access to all resources and can perform all administrative actions.